# How can I align a big div next to three stacked divs?

Tags: css, css-float

Three small divs, stacked upon each other, with a big three-small-divs-high div on their right side. How do I do this? Does Bootstrap have anything prepared for it?

[image]

Comment: You tagged `float`. Why not use it?

Comment: @Aloso I've tried! Failed miserably. Ended up with one small, next to a big div, with two stacked beneath it

Comment: @John Smith please post an example of what you tried.  That way specific direction can be given to fix your issue rather than creating an answer out of nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use any framework, you can do this with `Flexbox`.

```css
.content  {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}
.box {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.right {
  flex: 3;
  background: #22B14C;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {background: #ED1C24;}
.box:nth-child(2) {background: #00A2E8;}
.box:nth-child(3) {background: #FFAEC9;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="box">Small DIv</div>
    <div class="box">Small DIv</div>
    <div class="box">Small DIv</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">Big div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was brilliant! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```css
#left, #right {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#left .small {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 55px;
  padding: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#right {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 165px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
  <div class="small" style="color: #22B14C; background-color: #ED1C24">Small div</div>
  <div class="small" style="color: #FFAEC9; background-color: #00A2E8">Small div</div>
  <div class="small" style="color: #ED1C24; background-color: #FFAEC9">Small div</div>
</div>
<div id="right" style="color: #0099DB; background-color: #22B14C">Big div</div>
```

If you want that it has a width of 100%, use

```css
#right {
    /*    ...    */
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```